# Mongodb native driver ,connection string error

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I made a sandbox at mongolab.com and I am running server on local machine .

When I compile the "app.js" file

```
   var uri='mongodb://inyourpc:password@ds047198.mongolab.com:47198/fairywayrpg';
   mongodb.MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, db) {  
        if(err) throw err;
   }
```

It throws back following error: 
`"URL must be in format with mongodb://user:pass@host:port/dbname"`

Any suggestion, all open to ear. BTW I m using MongoDB new version 3.1.19 (I Believe).

Comment: I think the uri is fine, is there any any "connect" function runing?

Comment: mongodb.MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, db) {  
              if(err) throw err;
           }

Comment: Sorry for late reply,actually it's giving error at connect that uri has to be in different format ,when it is fine.BTW Anmol mentioned somethign about environment variables ,can it be the issue. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andrew was right ,that URI looked fine .
There was a space before mongodb,that made my URI false.P.S I added double quotes at start instead of single quotes.
That's all ,thanks everyone for your help ...!Grateful!

```
      "mongodb://inyourpc:password@ds047198.mongolab.com:47198/fairywayrpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to the environment variable on MongoLab.

> MONGOLAB_URI

The `MONGOLAB_URI` is in the below format.

URI format for Single-node plan:

`mongodb://dbuser:dbpass@host:port/dbname`

So, your code should be something like:

```
var mongoUri = process.env.MONGOLAB_URI;
mongo.connect( mongoUri, {}, dbConnectCallback );
function dbConnectCallback( error, db )
{
    database = db;

    database.addListener( "error", handleError );
    database.createCollection( "contacts", createCollectionCallback );
};
function handleError( error )
{
    console.log( "Error connecting to MongoLab\n" + error );
};
```

Comment: MONGOLAB_URL is coming undefined.Hence mongoUri is coming undefined as well.